# Перевод американских книг

Tags: фразеология, жаргон, переводы, английский-язык, идиомы

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, ресурсы для перевода американских книг. У меня небольшой опыт и словарный запас, поэтому часто возникают проблемы с переводом устойчивых выражений и оборотов речи. Например, фразу "even the news needs flavour" я перевела бы как "новости должны быть интересными", но мне сказали, что лучше перевести как: "новости должны быть колоритными".

Не посоветуете какие-то сайты, словари или книги, которые помогут с развитием словарного запаса? Часто пользуюсь ruscorpora, kartaslov и reverso.context, но и их в последнее время недостаточно.

Буду благодарна!

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он не подходит для данного сайта.

Comment: Найдите в соцсетях группы переводчиков или обратитесь на сайт «Город переводчиков».

Comment: Мне кажется, "новости не должны быть пресными" точнее.

Comment: @mustaccio, Спасибо, действительно, хороший вариант